# i have been trying to use For Loop in kotlin to ilterate through this JsonObject

Tags: android, json, kotlin

i have been trying to use For Loop in kotlin to ilterate through this JsonObject but i keep getting this error, can anyone help this is the whole kotlin class and the dummy json response i want to use.
PS "i am a beginner"

```
object QueryUtils {
    /** Sample JSON response for a USGS query  */
    private const val SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE =
        "{\"type\":\"FeatureCollection\",\"metadata\":{\"generated\":1462295443000,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?format=geojson&starttime=2016-01-01&endtime=2016-01-31&minmag=6&limit=10\",\"title\":\"USGS Earthquakes\",\"status\":200,\"api\":\"1.5.2\",\"limit\":10,\"offset\":1,\"count\":10},\"features\":[{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.2,\"place\":\"88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\",\"time\":1454124312220,\"updated\":1460674294040,\"tz\":720,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004vvx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004vvx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":2,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":5.82,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":798,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004vvx\",\"ids\":\",at00o1qxho,pt16030050,us20004vvx,gcmt20160130032510,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.958,\"rms\":1.19,\"gap\":17,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.2 - 88km N of Yelizovo, Russia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[158.5463,53.9776,177]},\"id\":\"us20004vvx\"},\n" + "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\",\"time\":1453777820750,\"updated\":1460156775040,\"tz\":600,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us20004uks\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us20004uks&format=geojson\",\"felt\":null,\"cdi\":null,\"mmi\":4.1,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":572,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"20004uks\",\"ids\":\",us20004uks,gcmt20160126031023,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.537,\"rms\":0.74,\"gap\":25,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 94km SSE of Taron, Papua New Guinea\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[153.2454,-5.2952,26]},\"id\":\"us20004uks\"},\n" +
      "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.3,\"place\":\"50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\",\"time\":1453695722730,\"updated\":1460156773040,\"tz\":0,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gy9\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gy9&format=geojson\",\"felt\":117,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":5.28,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":695,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gy9\",\"ids\":\",us10004gy9,gcmt20160125042203,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.201,\"rms\":0.92,\"gap\":20,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.3 - 50km NNE of Al Hoceima, Morocco\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-3.6818,35.6493,12]},\"id\":\"us10004gy9\"},\n" +
      "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":7.1,\"place\":\"86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\",\"time\":1453631430230,\"updated\":1460156770040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004gqp\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004gqp&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1816,\"cdi\":7.2,\"mmi\":6.6,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":1496,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004gqp\",\"ids\":\",at00o1gd6r,us10004gqp,ak12496371,gcmt20160124103030,\",\"sources\":\",at,us,ak,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,finite-fault,general-link,general-text,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,trump-origin,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.72,\"rms\":2.11,\"gap\":19,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 7.1 - 86km E of Old Iliamna, Alaska\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-153.4051,59.6363,129]},\"id\":\"us10004gqp\"},\n" +
     "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.6,\"place\":\"215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\",\"time\":1453399617650,\"updated\":1459963829040,\"tz\":-420,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004g4l\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004g4l&format=geojson\",\"felt\":11,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":3.92,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":673,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004g4l\",\"ids\":\",at00o1bebo,pt16021050,us10004g4l,gcmt20160121180659,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":2.413,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":74,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.6 - 215km SW of Tomatlan, Mexico\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-106.9337,18.8239,10]},\"id\":\"us10004g4l\"},\n" +
      "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.7,\"place\":\"52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\",\"time\":1452741933640,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebx\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebx&format=geojson\",\"felt\":51,\"cdi\":5.8,\"mmi\":6.45,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":720,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebx\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebx,pt16014050,at00o0xauk,gcmt20160114032534,\",\"sources\":\",us,pt,at,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",associate,cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":0.281,\"rms\":0.98,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.7 - 52km SE of Shizunai, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[142.781,41.9723,46]},\"id\":\"us10004ebx\"},\n" +
       "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.1,\"place\":\"12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\",\"time\":1452741928270,\"updated\":1459304879040,\"tz\":-240,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004ebw\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004ebw&format=geojson\",\"felt\":3,\"cdi\":2.2,\"mmi\":2.21,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":573,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004ebw\",\"ids\":\",us10004ebw,gcmt20160114032528,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":5.492,\"rms\":1.04,\"gap\":16,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.1 - 12km WNW of Charagua, Bolivia\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-63.3288,-19.7597,582.56]},\"id\":\"us10004ebw\"},\n" +
       "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.2,\"place\":\"74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\",\"time\":1452532083920,\"updated\":1459304875040,\"tz\":540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004djn\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004djn&format=geojson\",\"felt\":8,\"cdi\":3.4,\"mmi\":3.74,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":594,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004djn\",\"ids\":\",us10004djn,gcmt20160111170803,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":1.139,\"rms\":0.96,\"gap\":33,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.2 - 74km NW of Rumoi, Japan\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[141.0867,44.4761,238.81]},\"id\":\"us10004djn\"},\n" +
       "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6.5,\"place\":\"227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\",\"time\":1452530285900,\"updated\":1459304874040,\"tz\":480,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004dj5\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004dj5&format=geojson\",\"felt\":1,\"cdi\":2.7,\"mmi\":7.5,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":1,\"sig\":650,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004dj5\",\"ids\":\",at00o0srjp,pt16011050,us10004dj5,gcmt20160111163807,\",\"sources\":\",at,pt,us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,impact-link,impact-text,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":3.144,\"rms\":0.72,\"gap\":22,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.5 - 227km SE of Sarangani, Philippines\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[126.8621,3.8965,13]},\"id\":\"us10004dj5\"},\n" +
         "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"properties\":{\"mag\":6,\"place\":\"Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\",\"time\":1451986454620,\"updated\":1459202978040,\"tz\":-540,\"url\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/us10004bgk\",\"detail\":\"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=us10004bgk&format=geojson\",\"felt\":0,\"cdi\":1,\"mmi\":0,\"alert\":\"green\",\"status\":\"reviewed\",\"tsunami\":0,\"sig\":554,\"net\":\"us\",\"code\":\"10004bgk\",\"ids\":\",us10004bgk,gcmt20160105093415,\",\"sources\":\",us,gcmt,\",\"types\":\",cap,dyfi,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,\",\"nst\":null,\"dmin\":30.75,\"rms\":0.67,\"gap\":71,\"magType\":\"mww\",\"type\":\"earthquake\",\"title\":\"M 6.0 - Pacific-Antarctic Ridge\"},\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[-136.2603,-54.2906,10]},\"id\":\"us10004bgk\"}],\"bbox\":[-153.4051,-54.2906,10,158.5463,59.6363,582.56]}"

    /**
     * Return a list of [Content] objects that has been built up from
     * parsing a JSON response.
     */
    fun extractEarthquakes(): ArrayList<Content> {

        // Create an empty ArrayList that we can start adding earthquakes to
        val earthquakes: ArrayList<Content> = ArrayList<Content>()

        // Try to parse the SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE. If there's a problem with the way the JSON
        // is formatted, a JSONException exception object will be thrown.
        // Catch the exception so the app doesn't crash, and print the error message to the logs.
        try {

            // build up a list of Earthquake objects with the corresponding data.
            val baseJsonResponse = JSONObject(SAMPLE_JSON_RESPONSE)
            //get json array
            val earthQuakeJsonArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("features")
            //traverse the arrays
            for (item in earthQuakeJsonArray){
                val currentQuake = earthQuakeJsonArray.getJSONObject(item)
                val properties = currentQuake.getJSONObject("properties")
                val magnitude = properties.getString("mag")
                val location = properties.getString("place")
                val time = properties.getString("time")

                val earthquake = Content(magnitude,location,time)
                earthquakes.add(earthquake)
            }
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Comment: What data type is features object?

Comment: feature data  type is Json Array having an object in it

Comment: something like this "features":[{ }]

Comment: I am asking, what kind of data type is this array? It is Intiger,Long...Please update your question, post some extra info: Like whole Json response.

Comment: i have done that

Comment: Try something like: for (i in 0 until earthQuakeJsonArray.length()) {
    val item = array.getJSONObject(i)

    // Fill your object logic
}

Comment: that lifted a lot of bundle off my head. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Kotlin, you have to use length on Array, as Kotlin does not expose an iterator.

Solution is:

```
    for (i in 0 until earthQuakeJsonArray.length()) { 
        val item = array.getJSONObject(i) // Fill your object logic
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        //traverse the arrays
        for (item in 0 until earthQuakeJsonArray.length()){
            val currentQuake = earthQuakeJsonArray.getJSONObject(item)
            val properties = currentQuake.getJSONObject("properties")
            val magnitude = properties.getString("mag")
            val location = properties.getString("place")
            val time = properties.getString("time")

            val earthquake = Content(magnitude,location,time)
            earthquakes.add(earthquake)
        }
```